# Can I use solid state output and relay output with the same components?

Tags: relay, solid-state-relay, solenoid-valve, modbus, contactor

So I have a OTB1E0DM9LP Schinder Electric I/O distributed module and I want use it'output to control some 24v electro-valve's and some 24V contactors.

The module have

- 2 Solid-state outputs of 24V 0.3A
- 6 Relay outputs 30V 2A

I'm having 3 valves and 5 contactors.

Can I use the relay and the solid state output to control both the valves and the contactors?

[image]

[image: This means I can switch max 8A with the relay and 360mA with the Solid state?]

This means I can switch max 8A with the relay and 360mA with the Solid state?

Comment: The datasheet of your solid state relay will tell you what kind of inductive loads it can switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking can you mix or feed some of your devices from solid-state outputs and some from relays. The answer to that is yes, subject to the limits specified in the datasheet.

The device is supplied with both because for some applications the SS outputs are more reliable when used for high-frequency switching but they only work with DC. The relay outputs can be used on both DC and AC over a wide range of voltages and so are more flexible.